# How to integrate ModulePass into LLVM?

Tags: clang, llvm

I need to integrate ModulePass into LLVM(3.4) after all Module Passes. 
How can I do this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I think `PassManagerBuilder::populateModulePassManager` ([doc](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1PassManagerBuilder.html#a2d31fceb9968b84ca7bd648a07c29d00) | [source](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/PassManagerBuilder_8cpp_source.html#l00127)) is the proper place to add a module pass - just add it at the end there.

Answer (score 0):

[This Github project](https://github.com/eliben/llvm-clang-samples) has up-to-date samples of using LLVM & Clang, and it should build with recent releases like 3.4. The project contains a number of samples of using LLVM passes and adding new ones; check it out.

Specifically, there's a simple sample of writing a custom module pass and running it on a module [here](https://github.com/eliben/llvm-clang-samples/blob/master/src_llvm/simple_module_pass.cpp).